# How does "ee.reducer.mean()" work when applying a mask over an image if the spatial resoultions of the image and the mask aren't the same?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to calculate NDVI using MODIS images over corn fields. But I'd like to mask the areas which are not corn. The spatial resolution of MODIS images is 250m, but the resolution of the cropland layer(corn mask) is 30 m.

My question is that when I apply **a mean reducer** in the region, how does Google Earth Engine average the pixels over the **mismatched resolutions**?

Does it consider the **fraction** of non-masked pixels to calculate the average NDVI value? or Does it resample the pixels based on the given scale?
I don't understand it.

**Here is the code that I've written:**

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-89.61412300349288, 40.40775378018841],
          [-89.61412300349288, 40.36041952865337],
          [-89.49327339411788, 40.36041952865337],
          [-89.49327339411788, 40.40775378018841]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(geometry);

//corn 
var corn=ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/2018').select('cropland').eq(1);
Map.addLayer(corn,{},'corn');

//Calculating NDVI using MODIS image
var NDVI=ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
.filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
.select('NDVI').first().clip(geometry).multiply(0.0001);


//Applying corn mask
var masked_ndvi=NDVI.updateMask(corn); 
Map.addLayer(masked_ndvi,{},'masked_ndvi');

//Applying the reducer
print(masked_ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale:250
}));
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: It resamples the image using the scale you defined in your reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the most primitive level of Earth Engine, a band's value and mask are processed as *functions from coordinates to numeric values*.

When you use `reduceRegion()`, the reduction operation asks the image's bands for their value and mask at points on a grid — the spacing between the points being determined by the `scale` parameter of the reduction. At each point, the image will determine which of its actual stored pixels (assuming it's an image asset or straightforwardly derived from one) is closest to the requested point, and return that point.

This is in a sense the same process as produced the image *you are looking at*. You can see in your screenshot that the mask and the data have two different “original” pixel grids, and you're looking at it on a third pixel grid, that of your screen. Similarly, the reducer has its own grid determined by scale and CRS.

So, you can consider this process to be nearest-neighbor resampling, performed on the data value and mask separately. But if you use a fine enough `scale` on the reduction, the values will *act like* they're weighted/fractional, because, for example, a data pixel that is half-masked will be sampled half as many times as one that is fully unmasked, so it will contribute only half as much to the mean.